# Exporting pointer to class from library

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
__declspec(dllexport) ClassName *c;
```

placed in the header getting me a lot of error messages (up to 10), such as:

- syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
- missing type specifier - int assumed

not only in that header, but also around static functions in ClassName implementation, while doing

```
__declspec(dllexport) int *c;
```

compiles fine.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark it as `extern`. Also, make sure the definition of `ClassName` is visible.

Comment: `class ClassName;` did the magic, but I still wonder, why its needed if I have that `#include "ClassName.h"` earlier in the code with full class definition?